# Can I render all partials and their contents on a page with assemble?

Tags: assemble

I have a bunch of partials in the following directory structure:

```
src
└── content
    ├── pages
    │   ├── index.hbs
    │   └── patterns.hbs
    ├── partials
    │   ├── _footer-subpage.hbs
    │   ├── _footer.hbs
    │   ├── _head-subpage.hbs
    │   ├── _head.hbs
    │   └── patterns
    │       └── dropdown
    │           ├── dropdown.hbs
    │           └── dropdown.json
    └── templates
        ├── custom.hbs
        └── default.hbs
```

and I want to be able to loop over all partials within `src/content/partials/patterns` directory and output their contents on a page. A the moment I am manually including the partials like so:

```
{{> dropdown }}

{{> another-partial }}

{{> another-partial }}

...
```

Is it possible to do this dynamically like you can with [pages collections](http://assemble.io/docs/Pages-Collections.html)?

**Edit:**

Sorry, I should have been more detailed in what I'm trying to achieve. It's a bit more complex...

This is what I am currently doing in full detail but would like to do programmatically:

```
<h3>{{dropdown.info.title}}</h3>                                        <-- name

<p>{{dropdown.info.description}}</p>                                    <-- description


{{> dropdown dropdown }}

{{#markdown}}``\{{> dropdown dropdown }}``{{/markdown}}                 <-- example

<h4>dropdown.hbs</h4>

{{#markdown}}
{{embed 'src/content/partials/patterns/dropdown/dropdown.hbs' 'html'}}  <-- source
{{/markdown}}

<h4>dropdown.json</h4>

{{#markdown}}
{{embed 'src/content/partials/patterns/dropdown/dropdown.json' 'json'}} <-- data
{{/markdown}}
```

The `dropdown.info.title` is using the .json file within the same directory as the partial for data.

I'm basically replicating functionality from [pattern-lab.info](http://pattern-lab.info/docs/pattern-parameters.html) to pull in a bunch of components to create a library of "patterns" but don't want to do it manually.

Here's an example of the desired output.

[image: Sample "pattern"]

The code I'm using is here https://github.com/sheedy/ux-prototype (the "dev" branch).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [compose helper](https://github.com/helpers/handlebars-helper-compose)

You could then do...

```
{{compose src="src/content/partials/patterns/**/*.hbs"}}
  {{@content}}
{{/compose}}
```

Comment: Thanks @doowb! I gave that a shot but it just renders the source code of the file I reference. In any case I don't think that helper will do quite what I need it to. I've edited my original question to give a bit more context of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @jonschlinkert and I were just talking about this type of use case earlier today. I think once we get the refactor done (very soon) then this will be easier to do with a plugin (which is what we were talking about). Currently, I think you would need to write a custom plugin that reads in your patterns and their data, then use a custom helper to output what you need. I'm not thinking of anything else, right now, that would work for you.